# Получение php данных с MySQL и проверка их

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, веб-программирование

Делаю сайт. Мне нужно из MySQL получить значение пользователя его группы. Кто не понял, код внизу:

```
    <?php
        if ($pexgroup['pexgroup'] == 'admin'): // чтобы тут php получал данные из mysql и проверял на наличии значения
      ?>
      <a href="/cpanel">Admin Panel</a> <!-- если удачно, это отобразится -->
    <?php endif;?>
```

Но данный код не работает... Гуглил, пробовал многое, но либо сайт получает $pexgroup другого пользователя (id которого самый первый), либо же вообще не работал.

Пожалуйста, помогите? И можете задавать вопросы, если что-то не поняли и не можете помочь.

К комментарию:

```
<?php
require_once 'indexdb.php';
$pexgroup = mysqli_query($mysql, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `pexgroup` = '$pexgroup'");
#$pexgroup = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pexgroup);
$pexgroup = $_GET['pexgroup'];
?>
```

Скажу: данный код я изменял много раз, и искал разные варианты, поэтому здесь и есть случайный набор текста по виду. Точнее так оно и есть. Можете кто-нибудь помочь проредактировать его?

Comment: это примерно тут как по фотографии машины определить почему не работает мотор. Где ваш код обращения к  БД?

Comment: Вас даная строчка `$pexgroup = $_GET['pexgroup'];` не смущает?

Comment: Надо обязательно найти нормальный пример работы с БД. потому что написанное здесь - это просто случайный набор слов

Answer (score 0):

Что-то такое должно работать, если быть уверенным, что в indexdb.php происходит правильное подключение и переменная pexgroup в url передаётся.

```php
<?php
    require_once 'indexdb.php';
    $getPexgroup = $_GET['pexgroup'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `pexgroup` = '$getPexgroup'";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysql, $query);
    $pexgroup = mysqli_fetch_array($result)['pexgroup'];

    if ($pexgroup['pexgroup'] == 'admin') { 
      ?>
          <a href="/cpanel">Admin Panel</a> 
      <?
    }
?>
```

Comment: Не работает. Сделал точно как у вас

Comment: @Peffi, вы уверены, что подключение к БД происходит? Также, стоит проверить версию PHP - возможно стоит использовать mysql_query и mysql_fetch_array вместо mysqli_query и mysqli_fetch_array.

Comment: Уверен. Я проверял почти всегда - ошибки нету.
Щас проверил по поводу версии PHP. Сделал mysql_query и mysql_fetch_array, выдало следующее:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in /var/www/****/data/www/****/index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/****/data/www/****/index.php on line 5